# Python Tkinter appl uncoloured area

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I am creating a Python Tkinter application.  At the moment I am trying to set the background of the app to Python's default grey colour, but am having an issue where part of the screen isn't colouring properly.

[This is what the screen currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DF4R.jpg)

Now I went and intentionally coloured the current frame's background blue, and the container's background red so I could try and see the area that is uncoloured.  As you can see the white grey-ish area is neither part of the container or the frame, and I can't figure out how to get it's colour to change.  Here is my code:

Main.py:

```
from Interface import Interface

#Development environent variable.  Set to false when program is released to public
inDevelopment = True

#Sets up the Window
root = Interface(inDevelopment)
root['bg'] = 'red'

#Sets the Window TItle
root.title("Tester")

#Sets the Window size depending on if it is the release copy of the program
if inDevelopment:
    #Sets the window size. Disabled when Fullscreen enabled
    root.geometry("800x480") 
if not inDevelopment:
    #Sets the window to fullscreen.  Disabled when screen dimensions enabled
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

root.mainloop()
```

Interface.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from MeterGauge import Meter

TEXT_FONT = ("Arial", 11, "bold")
currentMeter = None
voltageMeter = None

class Interface(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, inDevelopment, *args, **kwargs):
        self.inDevelopment = inDevelopment
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = "nwes")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frames = { }

        for F in (DefaultScreen, TestScreen):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame            
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 25, pady = 25, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(DefaultScreen)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


# Screen which will be the default display
# Emulates release copy of program
class DefaultScreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.config(background='blue')

        frame_style = ttk.Style()
        frame_style.configure("My.TFrame", background = "grey")

        #Frame for Current Monitor
        currentMeterFrame = ttk.Frame(controller, style="My.TFrame")
        currentMeterFrame.place(height = 165, width = 185, x = 545, y = 25)

        #Frame for Voltage Monitor
        voltageMeterFrame = ttk.Frame(controller, style="My.TFrame")
        voltageMeterFrame.place(height = 165, width = 185, x = 545, y = 250)

        tc = TemperatureCommands()
        #Label for the Controller State
        lblControllerState = ttk.Label(self, text = "Controller State",
            background = "grey", font = TEXT_FONT).grid(
            column = 1, row = 1, columnspan = 5)

        #Label for the Temperature State
        lblTempState = ttk.Label(self, text = "this is test text",
        background = "grey", font = TEXT_FONT)
        lblTempState.grid(column = 1, row = 2, columnspan = 5)
        lblTempState.config(font=("", 14, "bold"))

        ttk.Label(self, width=20, background = "grey").grid(column = 1, row = 3, columnspan = 2)

        #High Cool Button
        btnHighCool = ttk.Button(self, text="High Cool", command = tc.HighCool).grid(
            column = 1, row = 4, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")

        #Medium Cool Button
        btnMediumCool = ttk.Button(self, text="Medium Cool", command = tc.MediumCool).grid(
            column = 1, row = 6, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")

        #Low Cool Button
        btnLowCool = ttk.Button(self, text="Low Cool", command = tc.LowCool).grid(
            column = 1, row = 8, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 2, sticky="nsew")

        #OFF Button
        btnOff = ttk.Button(self, text = "OFF", command = tc.Off).grid(
            column = 1, row = 10, columnspan = 5, rowspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")

        #Driver Button (disabled for release version)
        if controller.inDevelopment:
            btnDriver = ttk.Button(self, text= "Driver", command = tc.Driver).grid(
                column = 1, row = 12, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")

        #Passenger Button (disabled for release version)
        if controller.inDevelopment:
            btnPassenger = ttk.Button(self, text = "Passenger", command = tc.Passenger).grid(
                column = 4, row = 12, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")

        ttk.Label(self, width = 0, background = "grey").grid(column = 3, row = 3)
        ttk.Label(self, width = 20, background = "grey").grid(column = 4, row = 3, columnspan = 2)

        #High Heat Button
        btnHighHeat = ttk.Button(self, text="High Heat", command = tc.HighHeat).grid(
            column = 4, row = 4, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")
        #Medium Heat Button
        btnMediumHeat = ttk.Button(self, text = "Medium Heat", command = tc.MediumHeat).grid(
            column = 4, row = 6, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 2, sticky= "nsew")
        #Low Heat Button
        btnLowHeat = ttk.Button(self, text = "Low Heat", command = tc.LowHeat).grid(
            column = 4, row = 8, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")

        fill_Width = 5
        col_Num = 6
        for i in range(14):
            ttk.Label(self, width = fill_Width, background = "grey").grid(column = col_Num, row = i)

        row_Num = 14
        col_Num = 7
        n = 0
        col = 6
        for n in range(col):
            ttk.Label(self, width = fill_Width, background = "grey").grid(column = col_Num, row = row_Num)
            col_Num = col_Num + 1

        #Current Readout
        ttk.Label(self, text = "Current Draw", background = "grey").grid(column = 7, row = 1)
        lblCurrentDraw = ttk.Label(self, text = "0.00 A", foreground = "lime", background = "black").grid(
            column = 7, row = 2, sticky = "ew")

        #Voltage Readout
        ttk.Label(self, text = "Voltage Tester", background = "grey").grid(column = 7, row = 8)
        lblVoltageDraw = ttk.Label(self, text = "0.00 VDC", foreground = "lime", background = "black").grid(
            column = 7, row = 9, sticky = "ew")


        #Current Meter Gauge
        currentMeter = Meter(currentMeterFrame, height = 300, width = 300, background = "grey", highlightthickness = 0)
        currentMeter.SetRange(0.0, 5.0)
        currentMeter.place(x = 10, y = 2)
        current0 = ttk.Label(currentMeterFrame, text = "0.0", background = "grey").place(
            height = 18, width = 28, x = 0, y = 141)
        current1 = ttk.Label(currentMeterFrame, text = "1.0", background = "grey").place(
            height = 18, width = 28, x = 4, y = 100)
        current2 = ttk.Label(currentMeterFrame, text = "2.0", background = "grey").place(
            height = 18, width = 28, x = 21, y = 60)
        current3 = ttk.Label(currentMeterFrame, text = "3.0", background = "grey").place(
            height = 18, width = 28, x = 54, y = 27)
        current4 = ttk.Label(currentMeterFrame, text = "4.0", background = "grey").place(
            height = 18, width = 28, x = 97, y = 7)
        current5 = ttk.Label(currentMeterFrame, text = "5.0", background = "grey").place(
            height = 18, width = 28, x = 144, y = 1)

        #Voltage Meter Gauge
        voltageMeter = Meter(voltageMeterFrame, height = 300, width = 300, background = "grey", highlightthickness = 0)
        voltageMeter.SetRange(0, 15)
        voltageMeter.place(x = 10, y = 2)
        voltage1000 = ttk.Label(voltageMeterFrame, text = "0.0", background = "grey").place(
            height = 18, width = 28, x = 0, y = 141)
        voltage1200 = ttk.Label(voltageMeterFrame, text = "5.0", background = "grey").place(
            height = 18, width = 28, x = 21, y = 60)
        voltage1300 = ttk.Label(voltageMeterFrame, text = "10.0", background = "grey").place(
            height = 18, width = 28, x = 54, y = 27)
        voltage1500 = ttk.Label(voltageMeterFrame, text = "15.0", background = "grey").place(
            height = 18, width = 28, x = 144, y = 1)

        for child in self.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx = 5, pady = 5)



# Screen for testing new items before adding them to the main display
class TestScreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

I don't know exactly what it is that is causing the light grey area to appear.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, you colored the root window red. The container is what you are seeing. Try this: `container = tk.Frame(self, bg='green')`.

Comment: @Novel thank you.  Man do I feel dumb sometimes :P